# How to login via account spotify service to access certain data

Tags: c#, json, spotify

Accounts Service Base URL: https://accounts.spotify.com.
How to login by username and password and get Oauth.
I use Json.net.

```
  public string API_key = "f80ef2...";
    private string Access_Token = "BQByIoRXuupprvbOTVFVU..................1nUEo8-wAy";
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetCategories()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories?client_id=" + API_key + "&offset=0&limit=39&access_token=" + Access_Token;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I'm developing spotify and I want whole user login to spotify service ,get access token

Comment: other than file-> new project, have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Yes. Now I must get Oauth from web api and copy it and paste on app. I can't resfresh access token...

Comment: let's see some code then....

Comment: I need login and get access token -> refresh access token.

Comment: updated code. I need login to get access token

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should better start here
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/

You may also use (i.e.) GitHub for some spotify projects. Look at their code and try to reproduce what you need - but try to avoid 'copy and paste'. Since it seems that you are not that experienced you should try improving your skills.

When you ask yourself why you get downvoted: You did not provide your own code but asked for some. Stackoverflow's community will just help you with your code to get it working but it will not make you some. If you want that you should look for a Freelancer or something like that to do it for you.